# Static page with formatted post list

Tags: plugins, posts, pages

I'd be surprised if this doesn't get asked a lot, but I did a quick search and couldn't find an answer so...

I have a couple of Wordpress sites and in both cases I really want to have pages comprised of static content at the top (possibly a top image, title and one or more paragraphs) then, underneath, a nicely formatted list of posts that match a particular category.

I have searched for plugins and tried one that does provide links to posts (it's called "Latest Post Shortcode") but it's pretty ugly. I want the posts to appear formatted in the same way as they appear on a standard posts page (image and excerpt with "read more" link).

I don't really understand why Wordpress doesn't provide this out-of-the-box, I would imagine it is a fairly typical requirement. In my case, I have a travel website and I want a static page for each destination with some introductory text, followed by a list of posts related to that destination. Maybe I'm missing a trick and this is achievable some other way?

I've seen solutions that involve digging into the PHP - I am a developer but not with specific PHP skills and would prefer a plugin or technique that does not involve coding.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of to achieve this without any custom coding is if your theme already displays Category descriptions. When you edit a Category, there is a "description" field where you would place the static information. However, many themes don't display this information. So, if you try adding a Category Description in wp-admin and it doesn't appear on the Category front end, you would need to create a child theme, which basically means adding a very simplified "style.css" file into a new folder, copying your theme's "category.php" into your child theme folder, and then adding a call to display the Description in that file in the child theme.

A different approach would be to use a plugin to create a custom post type for each set of posts. So for example, if your categories are Apples and Bananas, you would create an "apple" CPT and a "banana" CPT. Make sure they are set up *not* to have an archive, and *to* use a rewrite. The "apple" CPT would need a rewrite of `array('slug' => 'apples')` so that the URLs of all of these appear to be "under" the URL `http://example.com/apples/`.

Here's the part where you need a bit of code. You would then need to create a child theme, which is as simple as making a directory inside `/wp-content/themes/` - let's call it `/wp-content/themes/wpse/` - and creating a file called `style.css` inside that folder:

```
/*
Theme Name: WPSE Starter
Template: twentytwenty
*/
```

The catch is, you'll need to change "twentytwenty" to the folder name of whatever theme you are actually using. So if you're using, say, the Ocean WP theme, its folder name (and the name you need to put in your file) is "oceanwp". Adjust as needed for your site.

Now for each category, you need to create a PHP file in your theme called "page-name.php". Instead of "name" though you need to use the CPT name. So in our Apples example, your file name will be "page-apples.php". Copy your own theme's page.php file contents and paste it into this file. Each theme uses whatever HTML it wants, so you can't use this code exactly as-is, you'll need to adjust it for your theme. But basically, what you need to achieve is:

```
<?php
// Get the sitewide header
get_header(); ?>
<main>
    <div class="static">
        <!-- Get the static content for this particular Page -->
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) :
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
        endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="posts">
        <!-- Get a few of the posts in this particular CPT -->
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'apple',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
        );
        $myposts = new WP_Query($args);
        // If any were found, output them
        if($myposts->have_posts()) {
            while($myposts->have_posts()) : $myposts->the_post();
                // You may be able to copy from your theme here
                // to output posts the same way your Categories do.
                // This will make an HTML article with just the
                // title of each post as a link to the full post.
                echo '<article><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';
                the_title();
                echo '</a></article>';
            endwhile;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</main>
<?php
// Get the sitewide footer
get_footer(); ?>
```

A third approach, using regular Posts, would be to use a custom field plugin such as ACF. With this approach, you'd create Posts and assign them to Categories, then create an ACF fieldset for each individual category, and that fieldset is where you would actually enter the data. But, you would still need to create a child theme to be able to actually display this information, and it wouldn't really have any advantages over using WP's built-in Category Description unless you have structured data.

Comment: Sorry, it's taken a while to look at your detailed response. I don't think the category description field is viable as I want all the formatting capability of the page editor to build up the static content. What I'd ideally like is a 'component' I could drop into the page that would allow me to pick a category (or tag(s)) and for it to then pull the most recent posts from the category and display them within the block. I'm a little surprised such a plugin doesn't already exist - maybe I've just not found it?

Comment: If you're using the Block Editor, there may be a block out there that does it. You can search for plugins that offer blocks and see if you can find one that meets your needs. WP Core has a recent posts block; it wouldn't surprise me if a "pick a category or tag, and show X posts" block also exists.